# Neo4j - How to enable access to Neo4j Browser for Neo4j Desktop from Chrome

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-browser

I have installed Neo4j Desktop 1.4.8 which runs Neo4j 4.2.11.
Neo4j Browser can be accessed from the in-built apps on Neo4j Desktop.
But I want to initiate an additional instance of the Neo4j Browser from Chrome.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

- Open the Neo4j Browser app from the Graph Apps menu in Neo4j Desktop
- In the browser, click on "Database Information" icon
- Under the "Connected as" heading, click on ":server user add"
- *Creating credentials for accessing through Chrome browser*
  In the new panel that appears below the command ":server user add" in the Query Edit Pane
  a) Username >> pick a username
  b) Password >> set a password
  c) Roles >> pick a role based on desired privileges ([described here](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/authentication-authorization/built-in-roles/))
  d) "Add User"
- Open chrome and go to "http://localhost:7474/browser/"
- Input the chosen credentials
  a) Connect URL >> neo4j://  localhost:7687
  b) Database - leave empty for default >>
  c) Authentication type >> Username / Password
  d) Username >> <chosen username>
  e) Password >> <chosen password>
  f) "Connect"

[image]

Comment: This works! You can check the ```Force password change``` box and your client will be able to start the browser, but then need to change their password before accessing the local database.